# x11vnc is slow, but using only 10% of available bandwidth

Tags: linux

I am using x11vnc over 15Mbit/s network with 20ms latency. When the screen is changing a lot x11vnc is slow - for example when I switch a tab in a browser, it takes almost two seconds until the view is fully redrawn.

The strange thing is that max connection speed of x11vnc is even during slow redrawing only about 10% of the available bandwidth. Why is x11vnc not using available bandwidth to speed the redrawing up? For example scp is using 100% of available bandwidth without problems.

How can I identify what is the bottleneck for x11vnc on my system? So far I think:

1. 10% network usage => network is not a bottleneck
2. fb read rate: 601 MB/sec => reading fb is not a bottleneck

Any ideas how can I further profile x11vnc and find out what is causing a slowdown?

For example is there any switch for x11vnc to show how much data it is handling and how long it takes to grab a screen, process and compress it and send it over the network?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my own question:

Switching from tight encoding to hextile encoding resolved the problem with slow redrawing completely.

To add some detail: I have noticed that during slow redrawing of the screen the cpu on the client was spiking to the 100% usage. I was using tight encoding and from the page [VNC Tight Encoder - Comparison Results](http://www.tightvnc.com/archive/compare.html) it can be seen that tight encoding is quite cpu intensive when compared to hextile encoding. After switching to hextile max cpu usage is never 100%, almost the whole available bandwidth is utilized and redrawing always takes less than a second. So the client's CPU was the bottleneck.

---

Or even better alternative (less bandwidth, low cpu usage and seems even faster than hextile) is to [compile x11vnc with TurboVNC support](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-turbovnc) and then use [TurboVNC client](http://www.virtualgl.org/Downloads/TurboVNC).

Comment: Here are some bandwidth and compression time comparisons http://www.tightvnc.com/archive/compare.html

Comment: How exactly did you change the encoding?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the screen capture/renderer is inefficient.  Many [different VNC implementations](http://www.dbuggr.com/milly/vnc-viewer-comparison-tightvnc-ultravnc-realvnc/) play around with this to achieve better performance.

If you don't need to reflect exactly what is on the local console, a better solution is [NoMachine's NX](http://www.nomachine.com/) or [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) as a remote desktop environment.  Performance is day and night compared to VNC even over WAN links.